# Utility in case one good is Bad and other is Good

Tags: economics, utility

I have a question

Suppose there are $2$ goods, $X$ and $Y$ where, $X$ is Good good, $Y$ is Bad good

Now Can the Utility be

1.) $U = x-y$

2.) $U = \frac{x}{y}$

3.) $U = \frac{\ln x}{y}$

They all are satisfying the simple definition of good and bad commodity

But For

1.) $U_x=1$ and $U_y=-1$

$U_{xx}=0$ and $U_{yy}=0$

So as $x$ goes up, $U_x$ is the same, Does that violate the Law of Marginal Diminishing Utility?

And What about $y$, Does that also have to hold the LMDU(Law of Marginal Diminishing Utility)?

And does $y$ violate it here?

2.) $U_x=\frac{1}{y}$ and $U_y=\frac{-x}{y^2}$

$U_{xx}=0$ and $U_{yy}=\frac{-2x}{y^3}$

Here, I have same question for $x$

And Here $U_{yy}<0$, That make LMDU hold, again does that matter for bad good?

3.) $U_x=\frac{1}{x.y}$ and $U_y=\frac{-\ln x}{y^2}$

$U_{xx}=\frac{-1}{x^2.y}$ and $U_{yy}=\frac{-2.\ln x}{y^3}$

This seems to be the ideal case, and LMDU holds for both $X$ and $Y$

The thing that cause confusion here is $U=xy$ (normal cobb-douglas)

For cobb-douglas, $U_x=y$, $U_y=x$, $U_{xx}=0=U_{yy}$

Does this even holds Law of Marginal Diminishing Utility, Of course it does I have been using it for a whole year now but then why is $U_{xx}$ and $U_{yy}$ not negative?

And I have another simple question about bad good, In any normal case where both goods are good we say MRS = $-|\frac{U_x}{U_y}|$ but what if $y$ is Bad good that does change anything

Does that change this to MRS = $|\frac{U_x}{U_y}|$ ?

I am getting really confused in these basics, Any help will be really really appreciated

Comment: check $U_{yy}$ in cases 2 and 3

Comment: @Golden_Ratio They seems to be correct to me, Did I make some mistake?

Comment: Check the sign.  Also, MRS is typically defined as the negative slope of the indifference curve.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_rate_of_substitution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of ordinal utility, there is no reason for utility to obey diminishing marginal utility.  Suppose $x,y\geq 0$ represent the amounts of goods 1 and 2 respectively.  Then the utility function

$$U(x,y):=\sqrt{xy}$$

represents exactly the same preferences as the utility function

$$V(x,y):=x^2y^2,$$

but $U$ exhibits diminishing marginal utility in each good, while $V$ exhibits increasing marginal utility in each good.

Diminishing MRS, on the other hand, is a meaningful feature of preferences.  This is because MRS reflects the maximum amount of one good an agent would be willing to trade for an additional unit of another good.  Note both $U,V$ above exhibit diminishing MRS.

Comment: Oh, So the above utilities 1, 2, 3 all are correct, Right (Just to confirm)?

Comment: Correct in what respect?  You can define a utility function however you want.  If the only requirement is that $x$ is good and $y$ is bad, then yes, all three of them are valid, but if you require other attributes for an agent's preferences, you need to specify what those attributes are.  The point is diminishing marginal utility is not meaningful for ordinal utility.

Comment: "An individual enjoys bus ride. However, buses emit smoke which he
dislikes. The individual’s utility function is: U = U(x, s), where x is the
distance (in km) traveled by bus and s is the amount of smoke consumed
from bus travel. So What could be the plausible alternative shapes of the indifference curve
between x and s?" That was the college entrance (that I am preparing for ) question that caused all this confusion, Seems Like All three of my answers were plausible Right?

Comment: They all are plausible right? Or Am I wrong?

Comment: So we know $U(x,s)$ is strictly increasing in $x$ and strictly decreasing in $s$. The question doesn't ask about a functional form of $U$; it only asks for plausible shapes of the indifference curve (which is a bit vague).  On the $x,s$ axis, any indifference curve must be increasing because if you get more of the "good," you also need more of the "bad" to be kept indifferent.  There are different increasing shapes, e.g. strictly concave, strictly convex, linear.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks, Thank you very much.

Comment: @SahilBagdi of course, no prob